# Eagle - export image of holes for component leads

Tags: pcb

I'm wondering if there is a generic method used by all cnc machines to create a png of the holes for component leads. As the Modella MDX-40 drills the holes first then mills the traces. All done at the same depth. I need a png of the holes which I then use on a different setting to drill all the way through. I'm using Eagle to create my layout.

I apologise if it's different for every cnc machine.

Answer (score 3):

Usually drill machines use Excellon drill files.  There are various ULPs and CAM processor jobs that come with Eagle to make it easy to export such files.  That's what I've always done and never had a board house complain or put drills in the wrong place or with wrong diameters.

Excellon is such a standard that whatever your drill machine is, it probably at least has software that can convert from Excellon format to whatever it uses internally.  A PNG file is a image, which doesn't make any sense for communicating drill information to a drill machine.